# No audio and microphone working on Asus 1101Eeepc

Tags: sound, drivers, microphone

I have just installed the latest distribution of Ubuntu (11.10), in my Asus netbook and -what a pitty- built in microphone is not working on Skype and also the speaker sound is worse. Seems something is wrong with the installed drivers.

Answer (score 3):

I have a ASUS 1005 HA, with the same problem. The following worked for me.

1. Install Pavucontrol
2. With Pavucontrol unlock the left and right channels of the microphone and set one channel to 0% and the the other to 90%
3. Open Skype, and disable automatically adjust microphone settings in the sound options panel

see also:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/433055

http://beboblog.johnbebo.com/2010/12/29/microphone-for-skype-in-ubuntu-1010-for-asus-1005ha.aspx

or check the following: The ACER 1810 T has the same issue.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks